# Define MapDataset shapes type in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I am trying to define type `<MapDataset shapes: ((None,), ()), types: (tf.int64, tf.int64)>`.

Right now i have `(<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([8, 3, 2, 1])>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=5>)` and i do not know how to turn it into this MapDataset.

I have been thinking about defining it in similar way to array but i cannot find anywhere this type to initialize it.